# Eclipse CDT, stop auto find

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I've recently been trying to setup a little toolchain for something with Eclipse CDT but I'm being driven insane by the default behaviors of Eclipse. It's just so against the grain of other IDEs for C/C++.

Is there anyway to disable the automatic searching of folders in the project directory for the source files? I want to manually add the files for it to compile instead of having to manually exclude all the files I don't want it to compile between multiple configurations.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your own makefile instead on relying on the eclipse auto generated makefile

Comment: Easily said for small projects but with a large project that depends on modular C libraries for embedded systems its kind of a PITA. The whole point of using an IDE is to automate the tasks, otherwise I would just use Notepad++